# Can someone recognize the CRS?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 and have some shapefiles with a "User Defined CRS" which I don't recognize. Is anyone able to recognize it?

Here is an image of the settings I see on QGIS. 
[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "recognize it": after all, it appears that your software has a complete set of parameters for this CRS, so what is there left to determine?

Comment: The thing is that I want to upload a delimited text layer with some points which have lat/long as CRS. So I have to convert those coordinates to the CRS of the whole map. If I do the other way around (convert the map to lat/long) it looses resolution (strangely).

Comment: You might get more value out of asking that question about how to import the text file using this custom CRS, rather than asking about something that might (at best) only lead to a work-around of your problem.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75167/problem-converting-coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [EPSG:6372](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn%3aogc%3adef%3acrs%3aEPSG%3a:6372&reportDetail=short&style=urn%3auuid%3areport-style%3adefault-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=), a projection for Mexico, defined by the  [Instituto Nacional de Estadística y Geografía (INEGI)](http://www.inegi.org.mx).

Comment: Do you know how to convert from that CRS to lat/long?!

Comment: @user20159: The same way that you would convert between other CRS's that QGIS supports: Select the layer, click "Layer / Save as" and choose "EPSG:4326" as the target CRS.

Comment: I mean to convert one punctual value (like 2799808, 1316921) to lat/long? I have a list of punctual values that I have to convert from one system to the other...

Comment: @user20159: You can use the `cs2cs` command line tool from the GDAL tools for that: Run `cs2cs +proj=lcc +lat_1=17.5 +lat_2=29.5 +lat_0=12 +lon_0=-102 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326` and then enter your coordinate `2799808 1316921`. It will return `99d2'25.637"W 23d51'30.394"N 0.000`. You can add the option `-f "%.6f"` to the command to get output in decimal degrees.

Comment: I don't have that tool, but for further reference I found this site, pretty cool: http://twcc.free.fr/. It converts almost every CRS. For EPSG:6372 I used SR-ORG:6700: Mexico INEGI Lambert Conformal Conic. Thanks so much Jake!

Answer (score 2):

That looks like [EPSG::6361](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn%3aogc%3adef%3acoordinateOperation%3aEPSG%3a:6361&reportDetail=short&style=urn%3auuid%3areport-style%3adefault-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=Mexico%20LCC) a.k.a. 'Mexico LCC'

The [EPSG Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org/) is good for finding the common names for different systems and datums.

Comment: Almost: EPSG:6361 is a "conversion", not a projection: It lacks the specification of the ellipsoid, which is present in the OP's `proj4` string. It looks like the projection in question is [EPSG:6372](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn%3aogc%3adef%3acrs%3aEPSG%3a:6372&reportDetail=short&style=urn%3auuid%3areport-style%3adefault-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=), which uses the same projection parameters, but also specifies the use of the GRS80 ellipsoid.

Answer (score 0):

your proj.4 string says it's a lambert conformal conic project with parallels at 17.5 ˚and 29.5˚ north, latitude origin at 12˚ north and longitude set at -102 ˚ west, false easting of 2500000, is using the ellipsoid of GRS80 and uses meters as a unit of measurement. Read about Proj.4 parameters here: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms

Looks like it's centered in the Pacific Ocean off central America somewhere.