# Problem converting coordinates

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, convert

I'm trying to convert punctual values from lat/long to EPSG:6372, a projection for Mexico, defined by the Instituto Nacional de Estadística y Geografía (INEGI). I found a converter online but somehow when uploading the converted values as a delimited text layer, the values appear to be displaces upwards (they should be on the map), as shown in the image. Does anybody knows why?

Thanks in advance.

PD I use QGIS 1.8.0

[image]

Comment: Did you try just using QGIS with on-the-fly reprojection? That is, just load the lat-lon into QGIS directly. If I'm not understanding you, can you consider editing your question to detail exactly what you did, what happened, and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: When you say "lat/lon", to with Datum are you referring too?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75118/can-someone-recognize-the-crs

Comment: @BradHards. I have the "On the fly reprojection" enabled. What I did in some steps:
1.- Convert points from lat/long to EPSG:6372
2.- Project the country map (which has that CRS)
Any ideas? 
3.- Uploaded the file with the converted points with the tool "add delimited text layer"
4.- Got the image I posted

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you want to convert? I used INEGIS's Traninv (http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/geodesia/traninv.aspx) to convert the location of Zocalo plaza in Mexico City (19.432674l -99.133191) to INEGI's CCL. Also I defined the CRS you mention (+proj=lcc +lat_1=17.5 +lat_2=29.5 +lat_0=12 +lon_0=-102 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ) in Qgis Custom crs definer and I have the same results (north=829065.704265, east= 2800164.104750).

Comment: @GerardoJimenez, thanks Gerardo I used that converter as well and now I got what I wanted!

Comment: When I suggested "editing the question", I meant "click edit below the question", not "add comments".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that both vector layer and point layer use the same CRS with `Rightclick -> Set CRS for layer`.

As EPSG:6372 is not a standard CRS delivered with QGIS, you have to create a `User defined coordinate system` for it.

The project should use the same CRS (but does not have to).

---

**EDIT**

You do not have to use an online tool for coordinate conversion.

Make sure that QGIS asks for CRS of new layers with `Settings -> Options` CRS Tab:

> Coordinate system for new layers: Prompt for CRS

Just load the data in lat/lon (WGS84), and the points should be in place, with `On-the-fly`enabled.

Use `Rightclick -> Save As ...` and select the custom CRS your vector layer already has created.