# Questions about EPSG:6372

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, vector-grid, mexico

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 and as CRS EPSG:6372 a projection for Mexico, defined by the Instituto Nacional de Estadística y Geografía (INEGI). I have the following questions:

1. If I measure the minimum distance between points projected with that CRS, what are the units? meters?!
2. I'm also doing some Vector Grids with maps projected with that CRS, when QGIS asks for the parameters for the grids (as in the attached image) are the units meters? So from the image I will be dividing the map into 10000 x 10000 m. squares, right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always look up EPSG definitions at the EPSG registry online:

https://epsg.org/

There you will find that units of that CRS are metres.

From this question

[Can someone recognize the CRS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75118/can-someone-recognize-the-crs)

I assume you have a custom CRS for it. In the definition string you can find an entry `+units=m` which should answer your question.

Your grid should come up with 10 km spacing with the configuration from the screenshot.

If you are in doubt about distances you measured, there might be something else going wrong in your layer configuration.